# Grails upgrade from 2.4.5 to 3.3.2: Relation 'xxx' does not exist

Tags: grails, grails-orm

is it required to do database migration for upgrading Grails 2.4.5 to 3.3.2 project. Currently, I m facing an issue in Bootstrap.groovy, application fails to start.

```
ERROR: Relation "department" does not exist

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; bad SQL grammar [n/a]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "department" does not exist
Position: 13
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertJdbcAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:731)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:719)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:303)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:117)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:242)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:159)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$save.call(Unknown Source)
at vaparigrails.Company.save(Company.groovy)
at vaparigrails.Company.save(Company.groovy)
```

Any ideas as to what the issue is. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
   DepartmentTag:

```
class DepartmentTag {
String name
String details
static constraints = {
}
static belongsTo = [department : Department]
 }
```

Department domain class:

```
class Department {
String name
String address
String postalCode=''
String phoneNumber=''
String email=''
String homeCounty=''
Float latitude
Float longitude
List speciality

static constraints = {
    homeCounty defaultValue: 'XXX'
    email nullable:true, defaultValue: ''
    phoneNumber nullable:true
    address nullable:true
    postalCode nullable:true
    homeCounty nullable:true
    latitude nullable:true, scale:6
    longitude nullable:true, scale:6
    speciality nullable: true      
}
static mapping = {
    vacancy lazy: false
}

static belongsTo = [company: Company]

static hasMany = [  speciality: String, tags : DepartmentTag,  comments:Comment, phoneContacts:PhoneContact, ipAddresses: IPAddress]  
static hasOne =  [ vacancy : Vacancy ]
```

Bootstrap.groovy

class BootStrap {

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    // Check whether the test data already exists.
    def openTag = new DepartmentTag(name:"name1", details:"details1").save(failOnError:true)
    def terTag = new DepartmentTag(name:"name2", details:"details2").save(failOnError:true)       
    }
   if(!Company.count()) {
        new Company(name: "company1", phoneNumber: "+12345", address: "address1", postalCode: "12345", email: "testi@testi.com", homeCounty: "XXX").save(failOnError: true)
                .addToDepartment(new Department(name: "department_name", speciality: ["speciality1", "speciality2"], address: "address1", postalCode: "12345", homeCounty: "XXX", phoneNumber: "12345", email: "testi@testi.com", vacancy: new Vacancy(maleVacancy: 4, femaleVacancy: 4, specialVacancy: 2)).addToTags(terTag)).save(failOnError: true)
```

Company domain class:

```
    class Company {
    String name
    String phoneNumber=''
    String address
    String postalCode=''
    String email=''
    String homeCounty=''

    static constraints = {
      email nullable:true, defaultValue: ''
      phoneNumber nullable:true
      address nullable:true
      postalCode nullable:true
      homeCounty nullable:true        
     }   
     static hasMany = [department: Department,users : WebUser]
    }
```

Comment: There are any number of reasons this might happen.  Can you show the problematic `BootStrap` code and the relevant domain class(es)?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the default values in the tables. Got help from Grails community, executed grails schema-export, started with an empty database and executed ddl.sql.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you updated from Hibernate 4 to 5 at the same time?  Hibernate 5 currently has an issue where it generates foreign keys differently: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10574

I'm not sure this is the issue you're seeing, but it might be related.  Even if not, it's something to be aware of.